# How to subscribe with youtube api?

Tags: node.js, youtube

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#subscribe_to_channel

Hello,

I cant figure how to subscribe to a youtube channel with a post request. Im not looking to use YoutubeSubscriptions as shown above. Im simple looking to pass an api key, but cant seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the YoutubeSubscriptions, you have to get the `session_token` after login youtube account.

The `session_token` is stored in the hidden input tag: 
`document.querySelector('input[name=session_token]').value`

or full-text search XSRF_TOKEN field, the corresponding value is session_token, reference regular:
`const regex = /\'XSRF_TOKEN\':(.*?)\"(.*?)\"/g`

Below is an implementation in Python:

```
def YouTubeSubscribe(url,SessionManager):
while(1):
    try:
        html = SessionManager.get(url).content
        session_token = (re.findall("XSRF_TOKEN\W*(.*)=", html , re.IGNORECASE)[0]).split('"')[0]
        id_yt = url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/channel/","")
        params = (('name', 'subscribeEndpoint'),)
        data = [
          ('sej', '{"clickTrackingParams":"","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"subscribeEndpoint":{"channelIds":["'+id_yt+'"],"params":"EgIIAg%3D%3D"}}'),
          ('session_token', session_token+"=="),
        ]
        response = SessionManager.post('https://www.youtube.com/service_ajax', params=params, data=data)
        check_state = json.loads(response.content)['code']
        if check_state == "SUCCESS":
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except Exception as e:
        print "[E] YouTubeSubscribe:"+ str(e)
        pass
```